# Count and group by multiple columns

Tags: powershell, count, group-by

I have a CSV file with the following columns:

- Error_ID
- Date
- hh (hour in two digit)
- Error description

It look like this:

[image: screenshot]

In SQL it was very easy:

```sql
SELECT X,Y,Count(1)
FROM #Table
GROUP BY X,Y
```

In PowerShell its a bit more different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) cmdlet allows grouping by multiple properties:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | Group-Object ErrorID, Date
```

which will give you a result like this:

```
Count Name          Group
----- ----          -----
    3 1, 15/07/2016 {@{ErrorID=1; Date=15/07/2016; Hour=16}, @{ErrorID=1; Da...
    1 2, 16/07/2016 {@{ErrorID=2; Date=16/07/2016; Hour=9}}
```

However, to display grouped values in tabular form like an SQL query would do you need to extract them from the groups with [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | Group-Object ErrorID, Date |
    Select-Object @{n='ErrorID';e={$_.Group[0].ErrorID}},
                  @{n='Date';e={$_.Group[0].Date}}, Count
```

which will produce output like this:

```
ErrorID Date       Count
------- ----       -----
1       15/07/2016     3
2       16/07/2016     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$csv = import-csv path/to/csv.csv
$csv | group-object errorid
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                                                                
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                                                                
    2 1                         {@{errorID=1; time=15/7/2016; description=bad}, @{errorID=1; time=15/8/2016; description=wow}}                                                                                       
    1 3                         {@{errorID=3; time=15/7/2016; description=worse}}                                                                                                                                    
    1 5                         {@{errorID=5; time=15/8/2016; description=the worst}}                          

$csv | where {$_.errorid -eq "2"}
errorID                                                                 time                                                                   description                                                           
-------                                                                 ----                                                                   -----------                                                           
1                                                                       15/7/2016                                                              bad                                                                   
1                                                                       15/8/2016                                                              wow
```

You can Pipe first and second example to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what i look for. Appriciate your help.